# Google Maps API v3 show local businesses/points of interest

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know at some point I'd come across a Google service built into their API that would provide local information as markers on the viewport (schools, hospitals, etc.)-- I believe this was a simple control that could be added just like the normal map controls, to allow users to turn it on or off with a checkbox or button.

I can't seem to find this feature documented anywhere in the v3.0 API docs. Can anyone provide some information on this, or let me know if it was deprecated?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Google Places API is what you are looking for.

[Google Places API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/)

Here is a snapshot of the partial JSON output:

```
   {
    "name": "Biaggio",
    "vicinity": "Pirrama Rd, Pyrmont",
    "types": [ "cafe", "food", "establishment" ],
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": -33.8666470,
        "lng": 151.1956500
      }
    },
```

Comment: thanks kjy112-- that does look very similar to the data that was being returned, but to implement this earlier service you only needed to enable a built in map layer, I believe.

Comment: hmmm this is probably it then: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/localsearch/index.html depreciated